# Using a variable key name to access $_GET / $_POST data in php

Tags: php, variables, post, get

I need to use a variable as the key to access the `$_GET` data.
Is it possible?

This is my code:

```
 if($_GET){
   for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
     echo $_GET["value0"];
     print_r(${'_GET["value'.$i.'"]'}); 
   } 
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I need to get `$_GET['value0']`, `$_GET['value1']`, and so on.

Comment: $_GET['value0'] = 'something' ?? I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Sounds like a little XY problem

Comment: `$_GET['value'.$i]` sounds like you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the existence of each value with `isset()` before trying to access it. Also in php you don't need any complex string manipulations to put your variable in a string. You can just literally "put your variable in the string":

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
     if(isset($_GET["value$i"])) {
         echo $_GET["value$i"]; 
     }
   }
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. So please kindly accept the answer (using the check mark on the left side of question)